# Moved to trash files but warning in git

Tags: git, macos, warnings

I have no idea with these warnings.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   ../../.bash_history
    modified:   ../../.cocoapods/repos/master (new commits)
    modified:   ../../.viminfo
    modified:   ../../.yunpan/1323472572_sync.db
    modified:   ../../.yunpan/log/360yunpan.log
    modified:   ../../.yunpan/log/network.log
    modified:   ../../.yunpan/system.db
    deleted:    ../My Gits/CHTableView
    modified:   ../../Downloads/ReactivePlayground-Starter/RWReactivePlayground.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/yiucha.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
    deleted:    ../../Downloads/Xcode_7.1.dmg.download/Info.plist
    deleted:    ../../Downloads/Xcode_7.1.dmg.download/Xcode_7.1.dmg
    modified:   ../../Music/iTunes/iTunes Library Extras.itdb
    modified:   ../../Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/ImageProxies.apdb"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/ImageProxies.apdb-wal"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Library.apdb"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Library.apdb-wal"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Person.db"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Person.db-wal"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Properties.apdb"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Properties.apdb-wal"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/Database/metaSchema.db"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/Database/metaSchema.db-wal"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/Database/metaSchema.db.lock"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/Engine/statistics.bin"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/Engine/store.cloudphotodb-shm"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/Engine/store.cloudphotodb-wal"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/cloudphotos-1.0.plist"
    modified:   "../../Pictures/Photos \345\233\276\345\272\223.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/lastsyncafterlaunch.plist"

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../../.Trash/1.jpg
    ../../.Trash/Screen Shot 2015-10-29 at 17.27.48.png
    ../../.Trash/Screen Shot 2015-10-29 at 17.28.53.png
    ../../.Trash/Xcode_7.1.dmg.download/
    ../../.Trash/hosts
    "../../360\344\272\221\347\233\230/"
    ../Part1/
    "../\346\210\221\346\230\257\345\211\215\350\250\200.md"
    "../\346\230\223\346\237\245\345\260\217\345\212\251\346\211\213/"
    ../../Library/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

On my mac, I use git, but now...
So many warnings, what should I do. Some of the files I have moved to trash, and emptied trash. Please help me and so many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried git clean?

Comment: Yes, I have tried git clean -f , -ff, -n -f and so on.. I should study hard with git..

Comment: And now,  still has one untracked file: Library/ I can't solve this warning, an d I am not sure how it occured.